# Notify user of account lockout at login (Solaris)

Tags: solaris, login, accounts

When logging into solaris, the user will normally get a username+password prompt.

If the password entered is wrong the prompt just re-appears, and it will just keep going without providing any indication of when a lockout has occurred.

Is there a way to modify this behaviour in Solaris version 9/10?

Comment: No way to change it because that is the correct security behaviour - not revealing why you can't authenticate.

Comment: That can be a question of security policy choice. Revealing the condition of the lock account state, does not amount to a gaping security exposure.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that revealing no information is the correct security behavior.  You may not consider it a gaping security exposure but most do as it can give someone an idea on if the account name is valid.

If you really want the reason for the login failure known, the only method I'm aware of is to write your own PAM module and add it to the PAM stack.

Comment: I suspect there is no "correct" behaviour as such here. To restrict behaviour into one rigid form seems to indicate a lack of openness.